# How to setup proxy authentication only once to the entire system?

Tags: proxy

I'm a newbie :)

My context: I installed Ubuntu in a desktop behind a proxy that needs authentication, its very very boring because I need to configure proxy's URL, and to enter my username and password in everything, example: firefox, eclipse, and etc...

I need something to leave it in a transparent way(for programs, it would be as if they are in a direct connection)

There is a natively way (or third-party program) that allows to storage my proxy authentication(preferably, encrypted), and Ubuntu ALWAYS use this information to ALL System and software?

Answer (score 2):

## Proxy parameters

File /etc/bash.bashrc:

```
    export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
    export https_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
    export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
```

File /etc/environment:

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
```

File /etc/apt/apt.conf:

```
 Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port";
 Acquire::https::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port";
 Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port";
```

clamav installed, file /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf

```
 HTTPProxyServer proxyserver.net
 HTTPProxyPort port
 HTTPProxyUsername username
 HTTPProxyPassword password
```

wgwt, file /etc/wgetrc:

In line 84 or where says:

```
 #use_proxy = on
```

Change to:

```
 use_proxy = on
```

And where says:

```
   #https_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
   #http_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
   #ftp_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
```

Change to:

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
```

Comment: but there is a way to centralize this configuration in one place?

Comment: No. There is not.

Comment: Don't forget git, `git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/` .. I'm hoping @kyodake is wrong because toggling this everywhere is really annoying

Answer (score 0):

You can set up automatic authentication by going to to your **System Settings -> Network**  Then change manual to automatic and set your proxys etc.

Comment: I can set url, port,  but I can not set user and pass